I mistakenly listed two degrees on my resume. Going through a background check
I received a full time offer & have just noticed while filling out the background check that there might be a huge issue. I have a bachelor's degree with a study abroad experience and I listed it on my CV like this:

School 1, Bachelor's degree, major
School 2, Bachelor's degree, major (exchange program)

I'm realizing this might look like two degrees. I provided transcripts during screening. And the transcript from school 2 clearly stated that I was an exchange student. I also talked about the exchange program very openly during all interviews. But I am still horrified because this can go wrong in so many ways with the background check company.
Should I directly contact HR? How screwed am I?
I literally did not mean to deceive anyone by the way. This was a pure mistake. School 1 is the target school I'm pretty sure my CV was chosen for. So I literally have zero reason to lie about having a second degree from no name school 2. But I can definitely see it being interpreted that way as dual degrees are also appreciated in the country I applied in.

"It is a really big offer for me". Did you get a job offer ?

Don't worry, nobody sane gets the same degree twice, especially not a bachelor. A human would understand it correctly. IMHO only an automatic scoring system (a bot) could get deceived, but you're long past that stage. I would be very surprised if they're still misinterpreting your CV.

So it's actually a master's (i just used a bachelor's to simplify). In the school system in our country, you get the choice between doing an exchange program or a dual degree program. It's very common to have dual masters, specially from that country I went to. And they are usually valued more. That's why I'm worried they would think i purposeflly misled them.

@Sarah: That's confusing. If you DO have a master you should list it as a master, not as a bachelor.


Should I directly contact HR?

Yes. Just call them.


How screwed am I ?

No worry. Everything will be fine if you explain your situation to HR.
You did not lie on your resume. So, an explanation to HR will clear up any potential misunderstanding. It will be fine in the end.
If a person says that they have a Bachelor's degree in physics when they actually have zero degree in physics, then that is a lie, and is a ground for the company to withdraw the job offer.

"Hey, I just realised something on my CV might be a bit confusing so I wanted to add a simple clearification before you waste precious time :)"

Be pre-emptive. If you act now, it'll be a mistake. If you wait until they bust you, it'll look more like lying.

This might be a gross generalisation, but based on personal experience in the UK Financial industry, chances are the background check will be conducted by a third party specialist company - they may well come up with other nit-picking questions as well, so given that it's a minor ambiguity in your cv rather than a fundamental lie I'd personally just wait for the initial response from them before saying anything.
And given that you've had an offer made already, your potential employer is likely to give you an opportunity to explain any discrepancies returned by the background checks because they'd probably want to avoid going back to the interview stage if there's been a genuine misunderstanding.
I've had similar in the past where I refused to provide references to a background check company for a previous (contracting) engagement that ended acrimoniously - I was given an opportunity to explain the reasons and provide alternate evidence of that engagement, rather than being immediately rejected.
Having said that, if you're worried about it you won't do any harm by contacting the HR department - they might just tell you to wait for the background check company to contact you anyway :-).
